# Finding the minimum of an integer part

Tags: optimization, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have the integers $k$ and $x$ that are such that $k \geq x \geq 2$.

I would like to find the biggest $x$ which satisfies the minimum of 
$$\left\lceil \frac{-1+\sqrt{4x^2-12x+8k+1}}{2}\right\rceil.$$

In other words, I'm seeking $\max_x \mathrm{argmin}_x \left\lceil\frac{-1+\sqrt{4x^2-12x+8k+1}}{2}\right\rceil.$

If I compute the derivative in the case of real numbers, I find $x=3/2$. So, I think the solution is $x=2$. But there are possibly other values $x > 2$ that produce the same minimum. What is the correct method to find the maximum of them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{-1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{4x^2-12x+8k+1}$.

Notice that this function have the same increasing and decreasing intervals as the function $g(x)=4x^2-12x$, since $f(x)$ is the composition of $g(x)$ with monotone functions: adding a constant, taking square root, adding another constant.

The minimum of f(x) is attained when $g(x)=4x^2-12x$ takes its minimum value, and that happens when $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and this minimum value is:

$f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\dfrac{-1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{8k-8}$.

Also, the function $f(x)$ is increasing for $x>\frac{3}{2}$, and decreasing for $x<\frac{3}{2}$, so to find the maximum integer $x$ such that 
$$F(x)=\left\lceil \frac{-1+\sqrt{4x^2-12x+8k+1}}{2}\right\rceil$$ is minimum, we have to solve the equation

$$F(x)=\left\lceil \frac{-1+\sqrt{4x^2-12x+8k+1}}{2}\right\rceil=\left\lceil \dfrac{-1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{8k-8}\right\rceil=F\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

This is a hard problem in general (because the ceiling function is so hard to work with) but we can at least give an upper bound for that: notice that such maximum integer $x$ must satisfy $f(x)<f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+1$, that means:

\begin{align*}
1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{8k-8}&>-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4x^2-12x+8k+1}\\
2+\sqrt{8k-8}&>\sqrt{4x^2-12x+8k+1}\\
4+4\sqrt{8k-8}+8k-8&>4x^2-12x+8k+1\\
4+4\sqrt{8k-8}&>4x^2-12x+9=(2x-3)^2\\
\sqrt{4+4\sqrt{8k-8}}&>2x-3
\end{align*}
and so, $\displaystyle{x<\dfrac{\sqrt{4+4\sqrt{8k-8}}+3}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems that there are sometimes solutions greater than $2$. Take for example $k=1000$, where $x=10$ satisfies the minimum (45).

Comment: That's right... you have to see how the factor 8k+1 affects the function.

Comment: I understand that I have to reinject the solution $x=2$ so as to find the maximum one.

Comment: That's Ok. I validate your answer ! Thanks again

Comment: I was finding the symmetry axis of the parabola $4x^2-12x$, which is $x=3/2$. In general I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think there exists a formula. I'm looking for it.

Comment: In fact $8k+1$ does not affect the symmetry axis. The formula for this axis is $-b/(2a)$ for an equation $y=ax^2 +bx +c$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok that does not help to solve the problem. I have to find another way.

Comment: Check the corrections for the answer. They might be useful.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem of the ceiling. Thanks again.

Comment: That depends on the initial assumption that $f(x)<f(3/2)-1$, but it might happen that there are better values with $f(x)<f(3/2)-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$, depending of "how integer" is $f(3/2)$. I guess if you have specific values of $k$ that you want to study then it might be easy, but to compute a general formula could be hard...